# How to fire Google Tag Manager event when global JavaScript variable equals a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to figure out how to trigger a Google Tag Manager event based on the value of a global JavaScript variable.  I see in the Google Tag Manager's Trigger view, we can set up a trigger for when a global JavaScript variable equals some value. However, for some reason, this trigger never fires.

I am previewing currently, and have saved my changes (clicked preview again) after making all changes, but for some reason, GTM isn't firing the trigger.

I've created a custom variable called "Screener Step" which has type "JavaScript Variable" and global variable name "screenerStep".  A trigger is set to when "Screener Step" is equal to "1".  It is set to 0 by default.

I've declared the variable "screenerStep" as global by defining it like so:

`window.screenerStep = 0`;

I can verify that `screenerStep` does in fact get set to `1` by typing `screenerStep` in the console, and verifying that it is equal to 1.

If it matters, I am using AngularJS to set the value of `screenerStep` within a `$watch`.

Thank you in advance.

**Update.**  The trigger does not fire even when `screenerStep` is initialized to `1` which is the trigger condition.

**Update.**  The problem was due to the fact that the trigger was actually a Custom Event that happened to have a filter to only trigger when `screenerStep` was equal to `1`.  After broadcasting an event via `document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('testEvent'));` the trigger did fire.  I will post a formalized solution after I figure out a few more things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want GTM to trigger based on a JavaScript variable's value, you need to do the following:

First, read this:  https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Then use the `dataLayer` to dispatch a custom event:

```
window.dataLayer.push(
  {'event': 'Your Custom Event'}
);
```

Note, you have to first initialize `dataLayer` as an empty array somewhere in your code. If you want the `dataLayer` to be available on page load, `dataLayer` needs to exist before your GTM container executes.

For my purposes (events), I just initialized `dataLayer` within my async loaded javascript.

You can then filter your GTM trigger to only fire if your global JavaScript variable equals a certain value.  To be clear, you need to first dispatch a custom event to instruct GTM to check your global JavaScript variable's value.  The global JavaScript variable is set in GTM as a variable -> JavaScript variable -> enter the global JavaScript variable's name.

Now, you may be thinking that it may be better to just have different event names for various conditions you wish to trigger GTM tags on. That's the path I chose in the end, which eliminates the need for global JavaScript variables altogether.  In some cases, however, it may be useful to pull in values from your JavaScript.  In these cases, we can add data to our custom events like so:

```
window.dataLayer.push(
  {'event': 'Custom Event'},
  {'attributes': {
    {'custom attribute 1': variableHere},
    {'custom attribute 2': anotherVariableHere},
    ...
  }
);
```

You can also just push variables to `dataLayer` directly.

```
window.dataLayer.push(
  {'custom variable 1': variableHere}
);
```